# step LR scheduler in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I am looking at some code from Facebook Research [here](https://github.com/facebookresearch/moco/blob/78b69cafae80bc74cd1a89ac3fb365dc20d157d3/main_moco.py#L372). It uses a stepwise learning rate scheduler as follows (ignoring the cosine learning rate scheduler):

```
def adjust_learning_rate(optimizer, epoch, args):
    """Decay the learning rate based on schedule"""
    lr = args.lr
    for milestone in args.schedule:
        lr *= 0.1 if epoch >= milestone else 1.
    for param_group in optimizer.param_groups:
        param_group['lr'] = lr
```

and the corresponding scheduler options is defined by:

```
parser.add_argument('--schedule', default=[120, 160], nargs='*', type=int,
                    help='learning rate schedule (when to drop lr by 10x)')
```

My understanding from the above is that at epochs *120* and *160*, the learning rate should be dropped by `10x`.

However, I think what these lines do:

```
    for milestone in args.schedule:
        lr *= 0.1 if epoch >= milestone else 1.
```

is to drop `lr` at *121*, *122*, *123*... It kind of does not make sense to me or I am missing something here? I think it should be:

```
    for milestone in args.schedule:
        lr *= 0.1 if epoch == milestone else 1.
```

Comment: It seems you're right. Have you check when this `adjust_learning_rate` function was called?

Comment: @Ivan yes I checked this: https://github.com/facebookresearch/moco/blob/78b69cafae80bc74cd1a89ac3fb365dc20d157d3/main_moco.py#L263 <-- it is called just after epoch start.. I wonder if it is something to do with multiprocessing - but I do not think so...

Comment: You should maybe create a new issue on their GitHub repository? That would clear things up.

Comment: @Ivan yes my colleague will do this.. Thank you - I just thought it was something stupid we could not understand and hence the SO post!

Comment: Ok, when you do, don't hesitate to post the issue link here. I'm interested in seeing what they say about it ;)

Comment: @Ivan ah I think I have found out why! urgh - i think it is because instead of using the current lr, the func refers to the lr it started with `lr = args.lr` I think this is why they have `>=` and not `==` I will test and report back...Does that make any sense to you :)

Comment: Indeed, I see what you mean: every time, it recomputes the resulting learning from `args.lr`. It's a rather strange way of implementing it!

Comment: @Ivan yes, the implementation caught us out! normally youd pass the current lr!